# While running Python application in EXE I get .. 'vba_extract.py' is not recognized

Tags: python, vba, operating-system, pyinstaller, xlsxwriter

I've created an `.EXE` file from Python scripy using pyinstaller.

Part of the program should get xlsm file and extract its VBA to bin file. I pass the xlsm file to the EXE using the `.spec` file:

```
datas=[('gen_ClipFile_V3p1.xlsm','.')],
```

Then, when the program gets to extract the 'vbaProject.bin' out of the xlsm file

I get the error:

> 'vba_extract.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command

My relevant code:

```
import xlsxwriter
import os
from pathlib import Path


# a function called by tkinter file open
def compareDesigns(self):

# find the EXE temporary working directory path
    bundle_dir = Path(getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', Path.cwd()))
    strbundle_dir = str(bundle_dir)
    XLSMtoExtract = os.path.join(strbundle_dir, 'gen_ClipFile_V3p1.xlsm')
    os.system("vba_extract.py" + XLSMtoExtract)
```

My spec file includes:

```
datas=[('gen_ClipFile_V3p1.xlsm','.')],
hiddenimports=['matplotlib', 'pathlib', 'time', 'sys', 're', 'operator', 'numpy', 'mplcursors', 'collections', 'xlsxwriter', 'os', 'tkinter', 'pyinstaller'],
```

I do manage to run the application on my machine, but other users with different machines reports this error.

I believe that I should find vba_extract.py path in the exe temporary area and reference to it but I do know how to that.

Answer (score 0):

If xlsxwriter is installed correctly then `vba_extract.py` should be added to the Windows %PATH%. However, that may not be available in the same environment your main script is running in.

Some suggestions, in reverse order of recommendation:

1. Figure out the path issue.
2. Ignore the path issue and include the `vba_extract.py` [code](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/master/examples/vba_extract.py) directly in your program. It isn't very big and you could leave out a lot of the exception handling if you know the target xlsm file is okay.
3. Ignore the macro extraction part and just ship the VBA macro with the code. This may also lead to path issues however.
4. You could also store the macro is hex/text format in your program and convert it back to a binary file, on the fly.